# C++ string length: Array elements vs glyphs

Tags: c++, utf, glyph

Does string::size return the number of array elements needed to represent the string, or the number of glyphs required to render the string? Does wstring behave the same?

Comment: It returns the number of array elements, each one of those being a single `char`. It does not include a null termination character.

Comment: and every char is a glyphs ?

Comment: ["Returns the number of `CharT` elements in the `string`, i.e. `std::distance(begin(), end())`."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

Comment: `std::string` knows absolutely nothing about glyphs.

Comment: The standard says 
*Returns: A count of the number of char-like objects currently in the string.* It's always a good place to look.

Comment: @ZangMingJie: no, absolutely not.

Comment: There's no notion of "glyph" in C++. If you want one, you have to provide and implement your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the number of `char`/`wchar_t` in the array. This allows a `std::string` to be encoded in `utf-8` which, as a single `char`, may have no meaning.